# How do I apply sturm comparison theorem to draw the conclusion?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Let $y$ be a non-trivial solution of the boundary value problem, $$y"+xy=0;x\in [a,b];y(a)=y(b)=0.$$ Then

1. $b>0$
2. $y$ is monotone in $(a,b)$ if $a<0<b$
3. $y'(a)=0$
4. $y$ has infinitely many zeroes.

My attempt:-
If $p(x)$ is continuous  and $p(x)\leq 0$ on $(a,b)$, then any non-trivial solution of the differential equation $$y"+p(x)y=0$$ has atmost one zero in $(a,b)$ and is monotone in $(a,b).$

> Using this theorem If $x\leq 0, $then $y$ has atmost one zero in
>   $(a,b)$ and is monotone in $(a,b)$ $\tag{1}$

(1) Suppose on contrary $b\leq 0$. Then $y$ is monotone by $(1)$. Which is not possible by Rolle's theorem.

(4) If $x\ge 1$ then by [Sturm comparison test](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-034-honors-differential-equations-spring-2009/lecture-notes-and-readings/MIT18_034s09_lec09.pdf) $$y"+xy=0;x\in [a,b];y(a)=y(b)=0.$$ has infinitely many zeroes.  I am confused.

Comment: What are these 4 points? Assumptions, claims that are true, claims that you have to prove or disprove? You could also name the equation, its basis solutions are known as Airy functions.

Comment: 2) connected with the boundary conditions seems strange, the only function satisfying both is the zero function. Of course, the zero function also has slope zero everywhere, and any point in the interval is a root.

Comment: The test is also known as the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have to decide if (1)-(4) are true or false. I don't understand how you are using Sturm comparison test.

First note that 3) is false. Indeed, if $y(a)=0$ and $y^{\prime}(a)=0$, then
writing $z_{1}=y$ and $z_{2}=y^{\prime}$, you have that $z=(z_{1},z_{2})$ is a
solution of a first order Cauchy problem
\begin{align*}
\frac{dz}{dx}  & =A(x)z\\
z(0)  & =(0,0)
\end{align*}
The only solution is $z=(0,0)$, which contradicts the fact that $y$ is non-trivial.

Next note that 4) is false. Assume there exist infinitely many $x_{n}\in(a,b)$
such that $y(x_{n})=0$. Since the sequence $x_{n}$ is bounded, you can find a
subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ such that $x_{n_{k}}\rightarrow x_{0}\in\lbrack a,b]$ (are you allowed to use this fact?).
Also, you can assume that either $x_{n_{k}}$ is strictly increasing, that is
$x_{n_{k}}<x_{n_{k+1}}$ for all $k$ or strictly decreasing, that is,
$x_{n_{k}}>x_{n_{k+1}}$ for all $k$. Let's assume the first. Since
$y(x_{n_{k}})=y(x_{n_{k+1}})=0$, by the mean value theorem, there exists
$z_{k}\in(x_{n_{k}},x_{n_{k+1}})$ such that
$$
0=y(x_{n_{k+1}})-y(x_{n_{k}})=y^{\prime}(z_{k})(x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_{k}}),
$$
which implies that $y^{\prime}(z_{k})=0$. By the squeeze theorem,
$z_{k}\rightarrow x_{0}$. By continuity of $y$ and of its derivative,
$0=y(x_{n_{k}})\rightarrow y(x_{0})$ and $0=y^{\prime}(z_{k})\rightarrow
y^{\prime}(x_{0})=0$, and so $y(x_{0})=y^{\prime}(x_{0})=0$. But this is
impossible, since reasoning as before the Cauchy problem
\begin{align*}
\frac{dz}{dx}  & =A(x)z\\
z(x_{0})  & =(0,0)
\end{align*}
has only the zero solution, which again contradicts the fact that $y$ is non-trivial.